# Are computable sets closed under XOR?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, automata

How do I prove if computable are/are't closed under XOR?

Comment: "computable" means recursive? i.e. decidable? It's unfortunate that now we have three words for the same thing.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: In computability theory, a set of natural numbers is called recursive, computable or decidable if there is an algorithm which terminates after a finite amount of time and correctly decides whether a given number belongs to the set.

Comment: Good. Then... what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Are computable sets closed under complement? intersection? union?

Comment: Closed under union and intersection. Not under complement.

Comment: Not so: they are closed under complement (why?)

Comment: Yeah right. Not closed under difference, sorry. But I don't know how to prove it. I need that in order top prove the XOR part of it.

Comment: If they're closed under complement and intersection then they're closed under difference. They are closed under difference.

Comment: That solves my problem. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Thought it might ;) You're welcome.

Comment: Note that this is specific to the computable sets; the computably enumerable sets are *not* closed under complement.

Answer (score 0):

If a set $X$ is computable, you have an algorithm $T_X(x)$ that returns true if $x$ is in $X$ and false otherwise.

Given two computable sets, the algorithm defined by $T_{A \triangle B}(x)=T_A(x) \,\operatorname{XOR}\, T_B(x)$ implies $A\triangle B$ is computable.